# Symfony EasyAdminBundle + FOSCKEditorBundle - type_options: { required: true } - не работает?

Tags: symfony, required, easyadmin

Всем привет !
Есть Symfony 4.3.5, PHP 7.2.
Установил EasyAdminBundle для админки и FOSCKEditorBundle, чтобы сделать из textarea WYSIWYG.

Все вроде работает, НО пока поле было типа textarea (`type: 'textarea'`) оно было обязательным для заполнения (красная звездочка у label есть), а когда я сделал из него WYSIWYG (`type: 'fos_ckeditor'`), обязательность перестала проверяться, хотя звездочка у label осталась. Ну и как следствие в БД пытается записаться null и выдается ошибка.

Поле в БД - NOT NULL. Я пробовал явно указать, что оно обязательное и указал в конфиге EasyAdmin:

```
type_options: { required: true }
```

но это почему-то игнорируется.

Так же пробовал в конфиге "fos_ckeditor.yaml" указывать: `input_sync: true` - это тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить группу валидации для поля

```
form_options: { validation_groups: ['Default'] }
```

Comment: Ничего не меняется. Пробую так:

`- { property: 'body', label: 'Содержимое', type: 'fos_ckeditor', type_options: { required: true }, form_options: { validation_groups: ['Default'] } }`